# Не находит stdint.h

Tags: c++, sfml, codeblocks

Я подключал `sfml` к `codeblocks`, запустил проект и получил ошибку

```
fatal error stdint.h: no such file or directory.
```

Ошибка была в файле `stdint.h`

В строке

```
#include_next<stdint.h>
```

Помогите я новичок в `sfml`.

Comment: stdint.h нет такого, есть stdin.h

Comment: Stdint в папке MinGW

Comment: @maint https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h Вот stdin.h как раз нет.